# HTML::Mason display progress as page is generated

Tags: html, perl, mason

I am forced to use [`HTML::Mason`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Mason) for the dynamically generated web page. Unfortunately, the page depends on some long running computation. I need to display progress to user somehow. Is it possible to make Mason not to wait until the page is fully generated?

Answer (score 1):

Having had a similar problem (though I was using Template Toolkit as the front end), the solution I used was to show the user a "query is in progress" page. This had a link that the user could click to check for results; if the query had finished, the results came up, and if not, another "progress" page was loaded. The page automatically refreshed after a certain amount of time so the user could just sit and wait if they preferred.

You could write some javascript that polls the server and dynamically loads the result into the page, rather than having the page reloading every *x* seconds.

Comment: This may be  a possible way to go... But the script looks quite complicated in this case: it should probably fork a slow process and then arrange reloads with checks to this slow process...

Comment: In my case, the script was calling an external program which produced a text file output that was then parsed to create the results. The script sent off the command, checked to see if there was an immediate response (e.g. if there was something in the user input that would make it fail immediately - in this case it would load an error page), and then "finish" the job by displaying the query in progress page. The link on the QiP page had the information required to find the text file with the results, so when the results were ready, they could be parsed and displayed.